# How much weight does a horizontal light socket hold?

Tags: light, security, socket

I have a porch light that is flush mounted with the sockets pointed sideways.   In order to hang a light bulb camera, I would need to install a socket extender to get the correct angle.  That would leave the socket then hanging freely.

Would that socket then be able to safely hold the weight of a security camera if the camera weighs 1-3 lbs? Or would it break down and be at risk?

Thank you

Comment: that cannot be answered ... all light fixtures are not the same

Comment: try reorienting the fixture so that the socket is vertical

Comment: Is there a way to reinforce the socket?

Comment: The socket is made to carry a light bulb, so what is the question

Comment: `Is there a way to reinforce the socket?` ... that cannot be answered ... all light fixtures are not the same ... only you know which light fixture you have

Answer (score 3):

##### TL;DR Seriously Reconsider This

I get the *concept*. Power is right there. "Hidden" that you even have a camera because it is "just a light bulb".

But I would be *extremely* cautious about this.

- The typical (I only checked a few) item of this type appears to be from some random foreign manufacturer with no indication of UL, ETL or similar assurance of safety when used directly with 120V AC power. That is not an issue with a typical USB or Power-over-Ethernet powered device, as there you can have a properly listed USB power adapter (note that not all of those are any good, but it is easy enough to get a good one of those) or network switch providing the power and the camera is low-voltage and relatively safe even if it it falls apart.
- I highly recommend wired network connections for cameras. I know that requires actual Ethernet or similar wiring, but it provides a connection that can't be blocked easily from a distance, doesn't get messed up when you replace your router, etc.
- If you have multiple porch lights, the lighting intensity, quality (CRI) and color will likely vary between the camera and the other lights.
- Other than slightly rotating the camera, you will have no way to aim it for a good image.
- When the light is turned off, you will have no camera. If you have the light normally on a dawn-to-dusk sensor (no camera during the day) or motion sensor, that will cause problems for the camera.

Top recommendation is a PoE camera - power and communications via a low-voltage cable. Next best (if you don't want to or can't run a cable) is to find a source for constant power (i.e., not controlled by a light switch) and connect a power adapter to power a separate WiFi-connected camera, which can then be positioned to provide the best coverage.

Comment: Some camera systems do offer a power adapter that screws in between bulb and socket -- but the ones I have seen just provide USB power via a cord to a separately mounted camera. (I currently have one of these installed.)